# ChatGPT OpenAI API coesn't understand prompt

Tags: c#, api, translation, openai-api

So i want to translate a specific prompt from for instance English to Netherlands and give 3 different options for this, sometimes it seems to work and sometimes ChatGPT gives text after the text he should translate. Because he doesn’t understand the prompt all the time, how can i fix this is there any way to make it better and more consistent to always give 3 translations and only translation text?

The following code makes the basic prompt for what he should translate to which language

```
public async Task<List<string>> TranslateVariant(TranslateModel model)
        {

            _model = new TranslateModel()
            {
                Default = model.Default,
                Variant = model.Variant,
                Property = model.Property,
                Id = model.Id
            };

            _textModel = new GenerateTextModel()
            {
                Prompt = $"Translate the following text from {_model.Default} to the language of the language code {_model.Variant} Only answer with the translation for that specific text nothing else. This is the text you should translate: {_model.Property} "
            };

            var choices = await _chatGPTService.CreateMultipleOptionsForTranslation(_textModel);

            return choices;
        }
```

This code will give 3 options and add a prompt with the previous message as an option already given, but sometimes the response gives me the translation with “Make it different than the previous translation” after the translation.

```
        {

            var api = new OpenAIAPI(_settings.ApiKey);
            var choices = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var result = await api.Chat.CreateChatCompletionAsync(new ChatRequest()
                {
                    Model = _model,
                    NumChoicesPerMessage = 1,
                    Temperature = 0.7,
                    MaxTokens = 2000,
                    PresencePenalty = 0.7,
                    Messages = new ChatMessage[]
                    {
                new ChatMessage(ChatMessageRole.User, model.Prompt)
                    }
                });

                var choice = result.Choices[0].Message.Content.Trim();
                bool isDuplicate = choices.Contains(choice);

                if (!isDuplicate)
                {
                    choices.Add(choice);
                    var optionNumber = choices.Count;
                    model.Prompt += $"{(optionNumber > 1 ? "and " : "")}Make it different than the previous translation {optionNumber}: {choice}";
                }
            }

            return choices;
        }
```

How can i make this better anyone got any ideas, or does the OpenAI API have a better way to give 3 options that are all different for a translation?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to make just one request instead of three separate requests and in the prompt of the single request ask Chart GPT to return three different translations.

When this prompt is sent:

> Translate "I am hungry" from English to Dutch. Return three different
> translations using synonyms, if possible. Return only the three
> translations delimited by pipe character.

The result is:

> Ik heb honger | Ik ben hongerig | Ik voel me hongerig

Not sure if it is correct, I do not speak Dutch.